# How to Map JPA Entities with Entities from an External Source

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistent

I have a spring boot application in which entities are stored in a database. these entities are fed by an external program through rest API.

Lets say I have an entity persisted as follows in my database

```
{
   id: 2,
   name: "SampleEntity",
   location: "local-drive"
}
```

When I call my external program it will give me an entity **without id** like following

```
{
   name: "SampleEntity",
   location: "local-drive"
}
```

Notice the **id is not available**. now **I don't need to save** this in database as this entity already exist in database. but if the entity is not available on database it should be persisted in database. I know what fields are unique for an entity so that I can search on database and save if not existing. but the problem is there are large number of fields for an entity and there are around 10000 entities provided by external program at a single execution.

I am thinking of a solution to store hashcode of object so that I can search using hashcode without searching for a large number of fields. I am not sure if this approach is a good practice. What I would like to know is are there any better ways to handle this kind of scenarios.

Comment: Change the primary key to a clustered primary key which only contains the fields you get form the external program

Comment: Don't use entites but SQL directly with in a type safe manner with a framework like jOOQ https://jooq.org

Comment: @XtremeBaumer clustered primary key is a good suggestion. But once data recived from external source it must have the ability to handle those data within the system.
For example: after object 'A' is saved with composite primary key from external source, I may need to change one field that belongs to composite primary key. once I update 'A' object it will be saved on data base as a new entity since the primary key is changed, and object 'A' remains same.
I need to address this issue too.